# Making zip file in Firefox plugin

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I developed a firefox plugin that store some data in plugin folder. How can I add a backup button, so when user click on it, a save dialog displayed and the folder be packed in a zip file and be stored in user's desired location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, the Add-on SDK doesn't have any modules to write ZIP files. However, with [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) you can access the [`nsIZipWriter` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIZipWriter) of the underlying platform. For example:

```js
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
var {FileUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var zipFile = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["test.zip"], false);
var savedFile = new FileUtils.File("C:\\foo.exe");
var zipWriter = Cc["@mozilla.org/zipwriter;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIZipWriter);
zipWriter.open(zipFile, FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY | FileUtils.MODE_CREATE);
zipWriter.addEntryFile("foo.exe", zipWriter.COMPRESSION_BEST, savedFile, false);
zipWriter.close();
```

This will create a `test.zip` file in the user's profile directory and write `c:\foo.exe` into it. See also [`FileUtils` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm).

Answer (score 2):

There's a [zip reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIZipReader) and [zip writer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIZipWriter) interface available.

Here's an example of using it in an SDK module: https://github.com/voldsoftware/ziputils-jplib/blob/master/lib/ziputils.js